# Query to compare multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am starting with SQL and i'm encountering something i don't know the awnser to.
I have a database with incidents (like descriptions of problems that occured with certain desktops) and other tables with the installed software and the hardware of the desktops.

I'm trying to make an SQL query that will only show incidents on workstations with common software installed. like i have 10 incidents of servers resetting, than i'd like to find out howmuch of these servers have the same set of installed software.

Currently i have this:

```
-- Query to find out how many times each omschriving (description) occurs
-- and to show only those that occur more than one time
SELECT incidents.omschrijving, COUNT(omschrijving) AS Aantal
  FROM hondsrug_db.incidents incidents
WHERE   (hardware.hardwareID = installed_software.hardwareID)
   AND (incidents.hardwareID = hardware.hardwareID)
GROUP BY incidents.omschrijving
HAVING COUNT(omschrijving) > 1
ORDER BY Aantal DESC
```

As visible in this ERD http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=oayr9i&s=8#.U4ibbfl_sbg  the table installed_software consists of 2 foreign keys. This is because a hardwarecomponent can have multiple softwarecomponents installed. What this means for this table is that a hardwareID can occur multiple times in the installed_software table, but each time with another softwareID.
Now i'd like to know that if you have 10 server incidents how do you find howmuch of the servers have the same set of software?

Thx in advance

Comment: your query should include at least the joins with the other tables in SELECT clause...

Comment: How is a server identified? Is it installed_software.hardwareID?

Answer (score 0):

The following query joins the `incidents`, `installed_software`, and `software` tables.

For each incident, the server (`hardwareID`) and the software (`softwareID`) are looked up from the `installed_software` table. The software name (`naam`) is looked up from the `software` table.

```
SELECT software.softwareID, software.naam, count(installed_software.hardwareID)
FROM hondsrug_db.incidents incidents
INNER JOIN  hondsrug_db.installed_software installed_software
ON incidents.hardwareID = hardwareID
INNER JOIN hondsrug_db.software software
ON installed_software.softwareID = software.softwareID
GROUP BY installed_software.softwareID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed 'omschrijving' contains the type of incident. You have to join this table to software table using hardware_ID as a key. You can also make another join to show not just software id but name too. (I skiped this step)

```
    SELECT incidents.omschrijving, installed_software.software_id, COUNT(omschrijving) AS Aantal
      FROM hondsrug_db.incidents incidents
    INNER JOIN hondsrug_db.installed_software installed_software 
    ON installed_software.hardwareID=incidents.hardwareID
    GROUP BY incidents.omschrijving, software_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(omschrijving) DESC
```

For analytical purposes I would export the result to excel and use cross-tables to anaylze it.